# QGIS freezes while executing code

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Im iterating through folders and subfolders to find shapefiles (~140 shapefiles, ~20 GB total) then applying `fixgeometries` and `importintopostgis` to import them to a postgis database.

While code is executing I would like QGIS to print out for example `Processing shapefile123.shp` but QGIS is freezing while code is running. All the while the import into postgis is working, I keep track on the side using pgadmin.

What is causing QGIS to freeze while the code is executing and how can I fix it? CPU and mem usage is about 50 %. Maybe [Tasks](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html) is what I want?

[image]

```
from subprocess import call
import os, datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now()
print ('start',str(datetime.datetime.now().time()))

#Create database
call(["psql", "-U", "postgres", "-c" "drop database if exists lmv;"])
call(["psql", "-U", "postgres", "-c" "create database lmv;"])
call(["psql", "-U", "postgres", "-d", "lmv", "-c", 'create extension postgis;create extension tablefunc;'])

root = r'C:\GIS\data' #Folder with subfolders with shapefiles

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.shp'):
            #print(os.path.join(path,name))
            if 'ok_riks' in path:
                prefix = 'ok_'
            elif 'vk_riks' in path:
                prefix = 'vk_'
            elif 'tk_riks' in path:
                prefix = 'tk_'
            elif 'fj_riks' in path:
                prefix = 'fj_'
            else:
                prefix = 'unknownsrc_'
            print('Reparerar: ', prefix+name)
            fixgeom = processing.run("native:fixgeometries", 
                {'INPUT':os.path.join(path,name),'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']
            print('Importerar: ', prefix+name)
            print('Tabellnamn: {0}'.format(prefix+name.replace(".shp","")))
            processing.run("qgis:importintopostgis", 
                {'INPUT':fixgeom,'DATABASE':'lmv','SCHEMA':'public','TABLENAME':prefix+name.replace(".shp",""),
                'PRIMARY_KEY':'','GEOMETRY_COLUMN':'wkb_geometry','ENCODING':'UTF-8','OVERWRITE':True,
                'CREATEINDEX':True,'LOWERCASE_NAMES':True,'DROP_STRING_LENGTH':False,'FORCE_SINGLEPART':False})

print ('stop',str(datetime.datetime.now().time()))
b = datetime.datetime.now()
print('Total tid {0} s ({1} min)'.format((b-a).seconds, ((b-a).seconds/60)))
```

Four hours later it unfreezes:

[image]

Comment: CPU is 50% of how many cores? QGIS and the algorithm are likely running on the same core. You could try running it in a different thread: https://www.opengis.ch/2018/06/22/threads-in-pyqgis3/